# How to make a 2D count table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a table with several fields, and I want to output a table with a count for all combinations of two of these fields. For example:

```
Table Computers
ID  | CPU Type  | GPU Type
---------------------------
1   | CPU A     | GPU A
2   | CPU A     | GPU B
3   | CPU B     | GPU C
4   | CPU B     | GPU A
5   | CPU C     | GPU B
6   | CPU D     | GPU C
7   | CPU D     | GPU B
8   | CPU D     | GPU B
9   | CPU E     | GPU E
10  | CPU A     | GPU A
```

And basically what I want to do is to create a bidimensional table of count where at each entry of this table there is a count of how many computers satisfy bot the row and column criteria:

```
        | GPU A | GPU B | GPU C | GPU D | GPU E |
-------------------------------------------------
CPU A   |   2   |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   |
CPU B   |   1   |   0   |   1   |   0   |   0   |
CPU C   |   0   |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   |
CPU D   |   0   |   2   |   1   |   0   |   0   |
CPU E   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0   |   1   |
```

Each of the two fields is a FOREIGN KEY in the correspondent table and there are tons of entries, so no chance to hardcode all the possible values.

How can I perform this query in MySQL. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This is called a pivot table.

Comment: Do you have to do all operations in SQL? Because in my opinion you should generate query dynamicaly.

Comment: I was looking for a full SQL solution. But from the answers it looks like that would be very difficult or even impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregate` to count the each `GPU Type`.

```
select `CPU Type`, 
count(case when `GPU Type` = 'GPU A' then 1 end) `GPU A`,
count(case when `GPU Type` = 'GPU B' then 1 end) `GPU B`,
count(case when `GPU Type` = 'GPU C' then 1 end) `GPU C`,
count(case when `GPU Type` = 'GPU D' then 1 end) `GPU D`,
count(case when `GPU Type` = 'GPU E' then 1 end) `GPU E`
from yourtable 
group by `CPU Type`
```

Answer (score 4):

As this can be any number of GPUs, but SQL can only deal with queries that return a before-known set of columns, there are basically two options:

1. Get all GPUs with one query. Then dynamically build a SQL query (in PHP, Java, or whatever you are using) to return one column per GPU.
2. Get the data in rows. Use your application (written in PHP, Java, or whatever) to build a grid from this data.

I'd prefer the second option. The query needed is simply:

```
select cpu_type, gpu_type, count(*)
from computers
group by cpu_type, gpu_type
order by cpu_type, gpu_type;
```

(AFAIK MySQL doesn't need the order by clause as it guarantees the records to be ordered according to the GROUP BY clause. However, this is non-standard behavior and might change some time. Better get used to properly use ORDER BY when you want your results ordered.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solutions. I ended up using the first approach you suggested and construct the query dynamically, since it is easier to show the final results table with the framework I am using. Your second approach looks also really simple, however it would be harder for me to manually construct the table. I am accepting NoDisplay answer since I basically used his answer and he answered first. Thanks so much. Best regards. Keep it up.

Comment: There's a third option that might be useful for someone else reading this. Get the data in rows as in the second option, export the table to a CSV file, and then use Google Sheets or Excel to build the pivot table (as, e.g., taught in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzgM5Aruh7w).